# When is QGLWidget's paintGL called?

Tags: qt, opengl, rendering, qglwidget

All I can find is "whenever the widget needs to be painted."

When is that, specifically?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you call `updateGL()` on your widget (or `update()`), or just Qt decides to redraw your widget. Reasons why Qt might choose to ask for a redraw include:

- your widget gets resized
- your widget is hidden and shown again
- your widget is minimized and then restored
- something else is put in front of your widget and then moved away
- the Moon is in the third quarter
- a distant butterfly had flapped its wings
- ...

In short, you have very little control about *when* Qt asks for a repaint. Just be sure to paint fast! :-)

Comment: Complimentary info: `paintGL()` is not even called "instantly" when you call `updateGL()`. Instead, Qt waits and call it later when appropriate, so that successive calls of `updateGL()` only result in one call of `paintGL()`.

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of the update() and updateGL() functions. Is this all from experience?

Comment: Do you mean, if that's a complete list of when Qt asks for repaints, apart from user-generated ones (i.e. calling `update()`)?

Comment: I'm just wondering where you got your info, really, since I wasn't able to find anything about it online. :)

Comment: Docs and source code. Docs say: `Each widget performs all painting operations from within its paintEvent() function. This is called whenever the widget needs to be redrawn, either as a result of some external change or when requested by the application.`

Comment: So I guess "some external change" in that quote could be expanded to "whatever external change Qt's implementers have decided requires a redraw". And it tends to be sensible, and the redraw is fast anyway so it doesn't matter that it's called often. And if I want to see the real nitty gritty details of when it repaints, I can check the source code.