# Calling the paintGL explicitly in QT

Tags: qt, qt5.3, qt3d

*IN Qt, the paintGL method is called automatically due to events mentioned in this post:
[When is QGLWidget's paintGL called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710514/when-is-qglwidgets-paintgl-called).
What do I need to do if I need to explicitly call the paintGL method from one of the class functions. 
    void CubeView::update()
    {
        QMatrix4x4 world;
        double posx=drawcursor();
        world.translate(posx,0,0);
        cube->setLocalTransform(world);
        std::cout<<"hi\n";
    //    QGLPainter paint;
    //    paintGL(&paint);*

This is follow up on my previous question as some things are now clear to me.

**1. You cannot explicitly call the paintGL method in qt.
2. QGLView class does not have the updateGL method- QGLWidget has it.**

Based on these my questions are:

1. Can I use the QGL widget class in qt3d. Will I be able to use all the features likeQGL builder etc here?
2. Is there any method in qglview which can substitute for the updategl method? Some method which is looked on before the paintgl class is called? Some function which is checked everytime before paintgl.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force a repaint without waiting the events processing, you can call `QGLWidget::updateGL()`. In this way `paintGL` is called immediately.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using qt3d and I am using QGLView class. It has the initializeGL and paintGL methods but it does not have the updateGL method.

Alternatively, is there any method that could work as an alternate to update method in qt3d?

Comment: To force a repaint on a QOpenGLWidget on qt5, just call its `update()` method with no arguments.